# Getting reference to array element where array is accessible as $obj->$propName

Tags: php, arrays, reference, variable-variables

Suppose that we have this code (simplified example):

```
$propertyName = 'items';
$foo = new \stdClass;
$foo->$propertyName = array(42);
```

At this point I 'd like to write an expression that evaluates to a reference to the value inside the array.

**Is it possible to do this? If so, how?**

An answer that will "do the job" but is **not** what I 'm looking for is this:

```
// Not acceptable: two statements
$temp = &$foo->$propertyName;
$temp = &$temp[0];
```

But why write it as two statements? Well, because this will not work:

```
// Will not work: PHP's fantastic grammar strikes again
// This is actually equivalent to $temp = &$foo->i
$temp = &$foo->$propertyName[0];
```

Of course `&$foo->items[0]` is another unacceptable solution because it fixes the property name.

*In case anyone is wondering about the strange requirements: I 'm doing this inside a loop where `$foo` itself is a reference to some node inside a graph. Any solution involving `$temp` would require an `unset($temp)` afterwards so that setting `$temp` on the next iteration does not completely mess up the graph; this `unset` requirement can be overlooked if you are not ultra careful around references, so I was wondering if there is a way to write this code such that there are less possibilities to introduce a bug.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambiguous expressions like that need some help for the parser:

```
$temp = &$foo->{$propertyName}[0];
```

Btw, this is the same regardless if you're looking for the variable alias (a.k.a. reference) or just the value. Both need it if you use the array-access notation.

Comment: Ouch -- I thought about this, but only tried `&{$foo->$propertyName}[0]` which is a compile-time error... PHP I love you so much more now. Thanks :)

Comment: Suggested read: [PHP Variable Names: Curly Brace Madness](http://cowburn.info/2008/01/12/php-vars-curly-braces/) and there are some related SO Questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1147937/367456 ;  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9844185/367456

Comment: Normally I 'd say "I know", but here "I should have known" is more appropriate. For more fun, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers/10333200#10333200

Answer (score 2):

It took some googling, but I found the solution:

```
$propertyName = 'items';
$foo = new \stdClass;
$foo->$propertyName = array(42);

$temp = &$foo->{$propertyName}[0]; // note the brackets

$temp++;

echo $temp;
print_r($foo->$propertyName);
```

This will print `43 array(43)`.

I found the solution in this article: [Referencing an array in a variable object property by Jeff Beeman](http://jeffbeeman.com/node/92)

Comment: +1 and thank you for answering. Wish I could accept both, but hakre was faster.